# How to count and tally numbers within a vector defined as a class object 'character'?

Tags: r, class

I am analyzing a survey, which is set out with the number of the question as a column while numbers are given to represent the answer. I.e

```
Ques1 
1
1
2
1
2
3
-1 ...
```

I am trying to count the number of occurrences from these numbers. Yet when I try to tally it says that "no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character" 
how do i get it to count the number of occurrences?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: To improve this question show us what you have done. Show source code and describe what it is doing and what you need it to do. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Hi just try `table(Ques1)` if all of your data is in a single vector.

If you data is inside a data.frame and `Ques1` is just one column, try
`table(yourdata$Ques1)`.